# Make obj and obj.clone() as same key in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, clone

Considering  -

```
public class Class_A {
    // members ...
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        ...
    }
}
```

And

```
HashMap<Class_A, Integer> m_map = new HashMap<Class_A, Integer>(); 
Class_A a1 = new Class_A() ; 
Class_A a2 = (Class_A) a1.clone();
m_map.put(a1,6) ;
```

Now , what could be done in order that also `m_map.get(a2)` will return `6` as `m_map.get(a1)`  ?

Comment: I think overrriding equals method on Class_A to look at the instance properties should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location in the `Map` is found by using the object's `hashCode` and `equals` methods, so the correct thing to do is to override these methods in your `Class_A` such that `a1.equals(a2)` is true and `a1.hashCode() == a2.hashCode()`.

However, this rings something of an alarm bell in my mind.  There's little reason to clone an immutable object, and `Map` keys should be immutable.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767365/updating-java-hashmap-key) for the risks of mutable keys.

Answer (score 3):

a1.equals(a2) must be true and a1.hashCode() must equal a2.hashCode().

So you must override equals and hashCode (the inherited methods from Object consider two different objects as non-equal and probably with different hashCodes...)